# Resample and interpolate timeseries in Python

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, resample

I have csv-file with wind direction (wd) and speed (ws):

```
datetime  wd  ws
06.02.2023 00:55  297  3.2
06.02.2023 01:55  296  2.7
06.02.2023 02:55  299  3.0
06.02.2023 03:55  302  3.5
```

I would like to resample the time to full hour, like so:

```
datetime  wd  ws
06.02.2023 01:00  297  3.2
06.02.2023 02:00  296  2.7
06.02.2023 03:00  299  3.0
06.02.2023 04:00  302  3.5
```

So far I have been trying with this script:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = r"data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep=";", skiprows=1, usecols = [0,3,4], names = ["datetime","wd","ws"])

# sspecifying the date format
df['index_time']= pd.to_datetime(df['local_time'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

# change date-time column to index
df.set_index('index_time', inplace=True)

# trying to resample
df_resampled = df.resample(rule='H')
```

print(df_resampled) OUTPUT:

```
                           local_time     wd   ws
index_time                                       
2023-02-06 00:00:00               NaN    NaN  NaN
2023-02-06 01:00:00               NaN    NaN  NaN
2023-02-06 02:00:00               NaN    NaN  NaN
2023-02-06 03:00:00               NaN    NaN  NaN
```

How can I resample only the time but leave the data as it was?

Comment: related : [Pandas reindex and interpolate time series efficiently (reindex drops data)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52701330/10197418)

Comment: You should be careful about interpolating wind direction. If the direction goes from 359 to 1, the average will be 180 which is obviously not what youre looking for.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I actually knew that but did not remember :D

Comment: Then how do I just resample the time, but leave the same data?

Comment: related #2 : [How can I interpolate the wind direction data in python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63880104/10197418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I have misunderstood but it seems that you just want to round the time up or down to the nearest hour? If so, then the following code should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {
    'date': ['06.02.2023', '06.02.2023', '06.02.2023', '06.02.2023'],
    'time': ['0:55', '1:55', '2:55', '3:55'],
    'wd': [297, 296, 299, 302],
    'ws': [3.2, 2.7, 3.0, 3.5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def round_up_to_nearest_hour(time_str):
    time_obj = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M') #Convert string of time to time object
    if time_obj.minute >= 30: #If minutes are above 30...
        time_obj += timedelta(hours=1) #...increase the hour by 1
    time_obj = time_obj.replace(minute=0) #Reset minutes to zero
    return time_obj.strftime('%H:%M') #Return the new time

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(round_up_to_nearest_hour) #Apply this function to all values in the time column of df
```

I ran this in Jupyter (See below: I switched one value to be below the 30 min mark) and it looks like it's doing what you want? Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I get TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.time

Comment: If I ask the type using df['time'].info I get answer dtype: object

Comment: Oh! ok, I think what's happened is that I copied the text of this post over and put the time into my dataframe as a string. I therefore needed to convert the string to a time object (i.e. `time_obj = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M')`).

I think your time values are already in the format of a time object. So, try deleting that line of code and replace time_str with time_obj in the first line of the function (i.e. the time object from your df is the input). That should do the trick?

Comment: note : you do not need vanilla Python datetime here. Use pandas dt accessor and round; `.dt.round("H")`. No `apply` needed.

Comment: Oh nice - I didn't know about that!! Thanks from me too :)